# Discord.py commands wont run when used under @client.command()

Tags: python, discord.py

i am attempting to use discord.ext commands to make my commands neater but the commands will not run

imports and intents:

```
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import requests
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
#Delcare imports
intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)
```

command:

```
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("pong")
```

i tried using

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)
```

however the following error message occurred:

```
    client = commands.Client(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)
AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'Client'
```

Comment: What do you mean? In your "i tried using" you are using `Bot()` but later on you are using `Client()`?

Comment: i attempted both client() and bot() bot returns an error  client runs but dosent register messages

Comment: So you're using Bot() and that gives an error message that says you're using Client()....? That's not how it works. Your error message said you tried ``commands.Client()``, which doesn't exist so you're getting an error for that.  Show the **real** error message you're getting when using commands. **Bot**. There's no way ``commands.Client`` "runs but doesn't register" - it literally doesn't exist, and it gives you the error you added to your post.

Comment: oh i apologize i see now i worded this terribly so here is me rewording it: running client.command give the error `client = commands.Client(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)
AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'Client'`. running **commands.bot** returns no error but attempting to run the command the bot does nothing

Answer (score 1):

Try only using bot and not client:

```
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import requests
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

load_dotenv()

TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

intents = discord.Intents().all() 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)

@bot.command() 
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("pong")

bot.run('DISCORD_TOKEN')
```